# how to find out all the time duration available for given date and start and end time : java

Tags: java, date

I have date and time in the format of Start Date and Time`15-05-15 02:00:AM`
End Date and Time `15-05-15 06:00:AM. with the time interval of`60 minutes`

how do i find out the hours available between these two dates and times?

the result would be

```
start Time : 15-05-15 02:00:AM end Time : 15-05-15 03:00:AM
start Time : 15-05-15 03:00:AM end Time : 15-05-15 04:00:AM
start Time : 15-05-15 05:00:AM end Time : 15-05-15 06:00:AM
```

please help me to handle in case the start date time and end date time range falls in next day range.

I am using `java 7`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Java 8

Start with [`LocalDateTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) to parse the `String` values to `LocalDateTime`

Then using a loop, increment the value of the "start" `LocalDateTime` using [`plusMinutes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusMinutes-long-) till the value is `equal` to or [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-) then the "end" `LocalDateTime`

```
String startAt = "15-05-15 02:00:AM";
String endAt = "15-05-15 06:00:AM";

String format = "dd-MM-yy hh:mm':'a";

LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startAt, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format));
LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.parse(endAt, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format));
while (endTime.isAfter(startTime)) {
    LocalDateTime next = startTime.plusMinutes(60);
    System.out.println("StartTime : " + startTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)) + "; End Time : " + next.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)));
    startTime = next;
}
```

Which prints out...

```
StartTime : 15-05-15 02:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 03:00:AM
StartTime : 15-05-15 03:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 04:00:AM
StartTime : 15-05-15 04:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 05:00:AM
StartTime : 15-05-15 05:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 06:00:AM
```

## Joda-Time (Every body else)

```
String startAt = "15-05-15 02:00:AM";
String endAt = "15-05-15 06:00:AM";

String format = "dd-MM-yy hh:mm':'a";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);

LocalDateTime startTime = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(startAt);
LocalDateTime endTime = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(endAt);

while (endTime.isAfter(startTime)) {
    LocalDateTime next = startTime.plusMinutes(60);
    System.out.println("StartTime : " + formatter.print(startTime) + "; End Time : " + formatter.print(next));
    startTime = next;
}
```

Which prints

```
StartTime : 15-05-15 02:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 03:00:AM
StartTime : 15-05-15 03:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 04:00:AM
StartTime : 15-05-15 04:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 05:00:AM
StartTime : 15-05-15 05:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 06:00:AM
```

## The "I'm not allowed to use third party libraries" (non-recommended method)

```
try {
    String startAt = "15-05-15 02:00:AM";
    String endAt = "15-05-15 06:00:AM";

    String format = "dd-MM-yy hh:mm':'a";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date startDate = sdf.parse(startAt);
    Date endDate = sdf.parse(endAt);

    Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCal.setTime(startDate);
    Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    endCal.setTime(endDate);

    while (endCal.after(startCal)) {

        String start = sdf.format(startCal.getTime());
        startCal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 60);
        String to = sdf.format(startCal.getTime());

        System.out.println("Start Time : " + start + "; End Time : " + to);

    }

} catch (ParseException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which prints...

```
Start Time : 15-05-15 02:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 03:00:AM
Start Time : 15-05-15 03:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 04:00:AM
Start Time : 15-05-15 04:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 05:00:AM
Start Time : 15-05-15 05:00:AM; End Time : 15-05-15 06:00:AM
```

Comment: why not Duration class?

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the answer would you please help me to do the same in java 7?

Comment: Can't we use DurationInstance.getSeconds(); Then we can apply the logic to convert it to appropriate format.

Comment: hmmm .. thanks for explanation. I just wanted to know thats another way too, right?

Comment: @BilboBaggins Been simply minded this works for ;). I might be missing something, but with `Duration`, you'd still need the time from point A and point A + 60 seconds...wouldn't you?

Comment: @MadProgrammer there is an API method Duration.between(Temporal, Temporal); so with a quick look I thought it should be usable, haven't tried it yet :) :) thanks for responses, I am new to java 8 and not using it in production.. :) :) but very enthusiastic about it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you and the last one helped me to solve my issues.

Comment: @Tony Just know, it's not really recommend any more (it can be unnecessarily complicated)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes but we are not using Java 8 and we not allowed to use third party libs(have to get permission from many). that is the reason why have to go with the second approach...

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.Date startDate;
java.util.Date endDate;
java.util.Date currDate = startDate;

while (currDate < endDate) {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(currDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);

    System.out.println("StartTime : " + startTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)) + "; End Time : " + cal.getTime().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)));
    currDate = cal.getTime();
}
```